# How can I play the RTSP stream by using libvlc

Tags: c++, rtsp, libvlc

I'm trying to use libvlc to play an RTSP stream. Here is my code:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    const char* fileName = "rtsp://184.72.239.149/vod/mp4://BigBuckBunny_175k.mov";
    int windId = this->winId();

    libvlc_instance_t *instance = libvlc_new(0, NULL);
    libvlc_media_t *vlcMedia = libvlc_media_new_location(instance, fileName);
    libvlc_media_player_t* player = libvlc_media_player_new_from_media(vlcMedia);

    libvlc_media_player_set_xwindow(player, windId);
    libvlc_media_player_play(player);
}
```

And the problem is that the libvlc will send an SETUP command to the server like this:

```
SETUP rtsp://184.72.239.149:554/vod/mp4://bigbuckbunny_175k.mov RTSP/1.0
```

It's completelty different from the vlc player. What the vlc player send is:

```
SETUP rtsp://184.72.239.149:554/vod/mp4://bigbuckbunny_175k.mov/trackID=0  
SETUP rtsp://184.72.239.149:554/vod/mp4://bigbuckbunny_175k.mov/trackID=1
```

Comment: I know this is an old thread but, did you find anything? Did you managed to make your rtsp stream work using libvlc's sdk??

Comment: Using QtVlc https://github.com/Orochimarufan/QtVlc

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple RTSP access plugins in libvlc. 
Make sure you are using live555 instead of realrtsp.